# How to find available versions for a bower dependency

Tags: bower

Let's say I want to include the latest version of jquery-ui in my bower.json. Is there any way of finding out which versions are available?

I see that I can find available components on http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/#!/search/jquery-ui but there doesn't seem to be any mention of versions.

Comment: The fact that this question exists is a huge usability fail on Bower's part.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can use info command to get information

for example:

Open a terminal and type

`bower info jquery-ui`

You will get a list of available versions as well

BTW: You can search via your terminal with:

```
bower search jquery-ui
```

Comment: I don't think `bower search` would give us the versions list.

Comment: `bower info` is the right command to get detailed info specific to a package.  
`bower search` prints all packages that has the query string as a substring.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for a version that hasn't been released yet, you can use `bower info <pkg> --verbose`

Answer (score 2):

Try [**`bower-update`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-update). It will check for updates and allow you to update packages one-by-one.

From it's own description:

> Updates Bower project’s components to the really latest versions, no matter what bower.json requires.

[image]

Comment: Looks like that package has been deprecated, and it suggests you use https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates instead.

Comment: `npm-check-updates` removed bower support in v7: https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates/blob/696168b350fd11ef8684b0c498328dc0aef870a3/CHANGELOG.md#700---2020-06-09

Answer (score 1):

In case you are working with IntelliJ IDEA (or WebStorm), you can [use its bower plugin](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/04/using-bower-in-webstorm/) to browse through through all available components find out their latest version:

[image: Screenshot]

It also offers a nice tabular view displaying current vs. latest versions of your installed components.